# How to make react-bootstrap modal stay same size and just scroll instead of expanding?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

```
<Modal size="lg" scrollable show={showInvModal} onHide={handleCloseInvModal}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Sell your items!</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <ItemCard
                        title="The Last Egg of 2012"
                        price="492"
                        image="https://rest-bf.blox.land/render/76692407"
                    />
                    <ItemCard
                        title="The Last Egg of 2012"
                        price="492"
                        image="https://rest-bf.blox.land/render/76692407"
                    />

                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCloseInvModal}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleCloseInvModal}>
                        Save Changes
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
```

[image: With Three Items]

[image: With Two Items]
I wanna keep it the same as the two items even when it's three, and just make it scrollable instead, does anyone have any idea for how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Modal` already has `scrollable` set for `Modal.Body` to be scrollable when overflowing.

Perhaps try style `Modal.Body` with a `maxHeight` so that it does not grow higher when at this point, instead becomes scrollable.

Example:

```
<Modal size="lg" scrollable show={showInvModal} onHide={handleCloseInvModal}>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Sell your items!</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  {/*  Add style for a custom max height and adjust value to fit use case */}
  <Modal.Body style={{ maxHeight: '650px' }}>
    <ItemCard
      title="The Last Egg of 2012"
      price="492"
      image="https://rest-bf.blox.land/render/76692407"
    />
    <ItemCard
      title="The Last Egg of 2012"
      price="492"
      image="https://rest-bf.blox.land/render/76692407"
    />
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCloseInvModal}>
      Close
    </Button>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleCloseInvModal}>
      Save Changes
    </Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```